# How to save plugin custom settings page fields

Tags: plugins, options, settings-api

I want to implement a plugin which gets 2 fields in admin area and saves those in options as array
I read the page [Custom Settings Page](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/custom-settings-page/) but seems it doesn't describe how to save fields values in options
How we can do it ?

Thank you

```
<?php

/**
 * Class for registering persian font settings page under Settings.
 */
class PersianFont_Options_Page {

    public $page_title;
    public $menu_title;
    public $plugin_slug;
    public $plugin_hook;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    function __construct() {

        $this->plugin_slug = 'persianfont';
        $this->page_title = __('تنظیمات افزونه فارسی ساز قالب', 'persianfont');
        $this->menu_title = __('فارسی ساز قالب', 'persianfont');

        add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'add_admin_menu' ] );

        // Here you can check if plugin is configured (e.g. check if some option is set). If not, add new hook.
        // In this example hook is always added.
        add_action( 'admin_notices', [ $this, 'add_admin_notices' ] );

        add_action( 'admin_init',  [ $this, 'register_settings' ] );
    }

    /**
    * Registers a new settings page under Settings.
    */
    function add_admin_menu() {
        $this->plugin_hook = 
            add_options_page(
                $this->page_title,
                $this->menu_title,
                'manage_options', // capability
                $this->plugin_slug,
                [ $this, 'settings_page_content' ] //output the content for this page
        );

        //var_dump($this->plugin_hook); // -> string(26) "settings_page_persian_font"
        if($this->plugin_hook){
            add_action( 'load-' . $this->plugin_hook, [ $this, 'on_plugin_page_load' ] );
        }

    }

    function on_plugin_page_load(){
        remove_action( 'admin_notices', [ $this, 'add_admin_notices' ] );
        $this->add_setting_page_help();
    }

    function add_admin_notices() {
        ?>
        <div id="notice" class="update-nag">
            <?php _e('افزونه فارسی ساز قالب پیکربندی نشده است. ', 'persianfont'); ?>
            <a href="<?php menu_page_url( $this->plugin_slug, true ); ?>"><?php _e('لطفا هم اکنون پیکربندی نمائید.', 'persianfont'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    function add_setting_page_help(){
        // We are in the correct screen because we are taking advantage of the load-* action (below)
        $help_content = 
            '<p>' . __( 'از این صفحه برای تنظیمات افزونه فارسی ساز قالب استفاده نمائید.', 'persianfont' ) . '</p>' .
            '';

        $screen = get_current_screen();
        //$screen->remove_help_tabs();
        $screen->add_help_tab(
        [
            'id'            => 'persianfont-default',
            'title'         => __( 'Help' ),
            'content'   => $help_content,
        ]);
        //add more help tabs as needed with unique id's

        // Help sidebars are optional
        $screen->set_help_sidebar(
            '<p><strong>' . __( 'For more information:' ) . '</strong></p>' .
            '<p><a href="https://parsmizban.com" target="_blank">' . _( 'بازدید از پارس میزبان' ) . '</a></p>'
        );
    }

    function register_settings() { // whitelist options
        register_setting(
            $this->plugin_slug, // option_group
            $this->plugin_slug, // option_name, for name property of tags
            [$this, 'process_inputs'] // sanitize_callback
        );
            add_settings_section(
                'load-font-setting', // id attribute of tags
                __('تنظیمات مربوط به بارگذاری فونت ها', 'persianfont'), // title heading for the section
                function($args){ ?>
                    <p id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['id'] ); ?>"><?php _e('با استفاده از تنظیمات زیر، تعیین نمائید که فونت ها برای کدام بخش های سایت بارگذاری شوند.', 'persianfont'); ?></p>
                <?php
                }, // callback function to display content at the top of the section
                $this->plugin_slug // plugin slug, created by add_options_page()
            );
                add_settings_field(
                    'frontend-font', // id attribute of tag
                    __('بارگذاری فونت برای بخش اصلی سایت', 'persianfont'), // Title as lable for field
                    function(){
                        var_dump(get_option( 'persianfont' ));
                        //$check_frontend_font = is_null(get_option( 'persianfont' )['frontend-font']) ? 'true' : get_option( 'persianfont' )['frontend-font'];
                        ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="frontend-font" id="frontend-font" value="true" <?php //checked( 'true', $check_frontend_font ); ?> />
                        <?php
                    }, // Callback function to echo input tag
                    $this->plugin_slug, // plugin slug, created by add_options_page()
                    'load-font-setting', // slug-name of the section
                    [
                        'label_for' => 'frontend-font', // label for => tag id
                        'class'     => 'frontend-font', // class for <tr>
                    ]
                );
                add_settings_field(
                    'backend-font', // id attribute of tag
                    __('بارگذاری فونت برای بخش مدیریت', 'persianfont'), // Title as lable for field
                    function(){
                        //$check_backend_font = is_null(get_option( 'persianfont' )['backend-font']) ? 'true' : get_option( 'persianfont' )['backend-font'];
                        ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="backend-font" id="backend-font" value="true" <?php //checked( 'true', $check_backend_font ); ?> />
                    <?php
                    }, // Callback function to echo input tag
                    $this->plugin_slug, // plugin slug, created by add_options_page()
                    'load-font-setting', // slug-name of the section
                    [
                        'label_for' => 'backend-font', // label for => tag id
                        'class'     => 'backend-font',  // class for <tr>
                    ]
                );

    }

    /**
     * Sanitize each setting field as needed
     *
     * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
     */
    public function process_inputs( $input ){
        // sanitize functions:
        // sanitize_email(), sanitize_file_name(), sanitize_html_class(), sanitize_key(), sanitize_meta(), sanitize_mime_type(),
        // sanitize_option(), sanitize_sql_orderby(), sanitize_text_field(), sanitize_textarea_field(), sanitize_title(),
        // sanitize_title_for_query(), sanitize_title_with_dashes(), sanitize_user()
        $options = [];
        if( isset( $input['frontend-font'] ) and $input['frontend-font'] == true ) {
            $options['frontend-font'] = true;
        }else{
            $options['frontend-font'] = false;
        }
        if( isset( $input['backend-font'] ) and $input['backend-font'] == true ){
            $options['backend-font'] = true;
        }else{
            $options['backend-font'] = false;
        }
        //update_option('persianfont', $options);

        // add error/update messages
        // check if the user have submitted the settings
        // wordpress will add the "settings-updated" $_GET parameter to the url
/*      if ( isset( $_GET['settings-updated'] ) ) {
            // add settings saved message with the class of "updated"
            add_settings_error(
                'persianfont_messages', // Slug title of setting
                'wporg_message', // Slug-name , Used as part of 'id' attribute in HTML output.
                __( 'تنظیمات مورد نظر ذخیره شد.', 'persianfont' ), // message text, will be shown inside styled <div> and <p> tags
                'updated' // Message type, controls HTML class. Accepts 'error' or 'updated'.
            );
        }*/
        return $input;
    }

    /**
     * Settings page display callback.
     */
    function settings_page_content() {
        // check user capabilities
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) { return; }

        // var_dump( wp_load_alloptions() ); // print all options

        // show error/update messages
        settings_errors( 'persianfont_messages' );
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1 class="wp-heading-inline"><?php echo esc_html($this->page_title); ?></h1>
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                submit_button();
                settings_fields( $this->plugin_slug ); // This prints out all hidden setting fields
                do_settings_sections( $this->plugin_slug );
                submit_button();
            ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

} // class

new PersianFont_Options_Page;
```

Comment: It says about Settings API, that's what you can use to create and update the two fields you need.

Comment: @sven So you mean that it does the saving rules itself?

Comment: Yeah, Settings API takes care of it.

Comment: @sven But it doesn't!

Comment: You can add your code in here, so that I can take a look!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63975/discussion-between-farhad-sakhaei-and-sven).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something was wrong with the naming, I had to change the field names, and it works ok.

From your code sample, this:

```
            add_settings_field(
                'frontend-font', // id attribute of tag
                __('بارگذاری فونت برای بخش اصلی سایت', 'persianfont'), // Title as lable for field
                function(){
                    var_dump(get_option( 'persianfont' ));
                    //$check_frontend_font = is_null(get_option( 'persianfont' )['frontend-font']) ? 'true' : get_option( 'persianfont' )['frontend-font'];
                    ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="frontend-font" id="frontend-font" value="true" <?php //checked( 'true', $check_frontend_font ); ?> />
                    <?php
                }, // Callback function to echo input tag
                $this->plugin_slug, // plugin slug, created by add_options_page()
                'load-font-setting', // slug-name of the section
                [
                    'label_for' => 'frontend-font', // label for => tag id
                    'class'     => 'frontend-font', // class for <tr>
                ]
            );
```

should be modified to:

```
add_settings_field(
        'frontend-font', // id attribute of tag
        __( 'بارگذاری فونت برای بخش اصلی سایت', 'persianfont' ), // Title as lable for field
        function ($args) {

            //$check_frontend_font = is_null(get_option( 'persianfont' )['frontend-font']) ? 'true' : get_option( 'persianfont' )['frontend-font'];
            $persian_font = get_option('persianfont');
            $frontend = !empty( $persian_font ['frontend'] ) ? $persian_font['frontend'] : false;
            ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="persianfont[frontend]" id="frontend-font"
                   value="true" <?php checked( 'true', $frontend );
            ?> />
            <?php
        }, // Callback function to echo input tag
        $this->plugin_slug, // plugin slug, created by add_options_page()
        'load-font-setting', // slug-name of the section
        [
            'label_for' => 'frontend-font', // label for => tag id
            'class'     => 'frontend-font',    // class for <tr>
        ]
    );
```

And the other one:

```
add_settings_field(
        'backend-font', // id attribute of tag
        __( 'بارگذاری فونت برای بخش مدیریت', 'persianfont' ), // Title as lable for field
        function ($args) {
            $persian_font = get_option('persianfont');
            $backend = !empty( $persian_font ['backend'] ) ? $persian_font['backend'] : false;
            //$check_backend_font = is_null(get_option( 'persianfont' )['backend-font']) ? 'true' : get_option( 'persianfont' )['backend-font'];
            ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="persianfont[backend]" id="backend-font"
                   value="true" <?php checked( 'true', $backend );
            ?> />
            <?php
        }, // Callback function to echo input tag
        $this->plugin_slug, // plugin slug, created by add_options_page()
        'load-font-setting', // slug-name of the section
        [
            'label_for' => 'backend-font', // label for => tag id
            'class'     => 'backend-font',    // class for <tr>
        ]
    );
```

I've made changes to callback function only.

Comment: I put the $args and get the value using var_dump, it outputs
array (size=2)
  'label_for' => string 'frontend-font' (length=13)
  'class' => string 'frontend-font' (length=13)

Comment: and also I get this error:Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\persian-font\options.php on line 110

Comment: @FarhadSakhaei I've added a wrong suggestion, figuring it out, and will update answer soon.